# Method to shift array element forward but eventually needs to appear first

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble shifting the array to the right,I wanna create a method that shifts all array elements forward, last element needs to eventually appear first at index 0.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ShiftForward {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] my_array = {1,2,3,4,5};
modify(my_array);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(my_array)); //must return 5,1,2,3,4
}
public static void modify(int[] m) {
int start = m[0];
System.arraycopy(m,4 ,m,0, m.length -4);
m[m.length -1] = start;
```

My current code returns 5,2,3,4,1, whereas I need the return to be 5,1,2,3,4 Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're starting at index 4 for your array copy, try it from index 1

Comment: What you're doing is called [*rotating* an array](https://www.google.com/search?q=rotate+array). <-- Google link to multiple solutions

Answer (score 0):

Draw what you want on a piece of paper:

```
Index:   0   1   2   3   4

Input:   1   2   3   4   5
         └─┐ └─┐ └─┐ └─┐ ┆
         ┌┄┼┄┄┄┼┄┄┄┼┄┄┄┼┄┘
         ┆ └─┐ └─┐ └─┐ └─┐
Output:  5   1   2   3   4
```

So:

- Save value at index 4
- Move 4 values starting at index 0 to index 1
- Store saved value at index 0

That is **not** what this code is doing, if `m` has length 5:

```
int start = m[0];                           // Save value at index 0?
System.arraycopy(m, 4, m, 0, m.length - 4); // Move 1 value? From index 4? To index 0?
m[m.length - 1] = start;                    // Store value at index 4?
```

It's like you're trying to rotate the other way.

I'll leave it to you to actually fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void shiftRight(int[] m) {
    final int lastIndex = m.length - 1;
    final int last = m[lastIndex];
    System.arraycopy(m, 0, m, 1, lastIndex);
    m[0] = last;
}
```